# Which permission allows triggering of an Azure Function

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I'm looking to create a custom role that allows someone to ONLY trigger an Azure Function (I guess they need sufficient permissions to be able to see it too), nothing else.

I've been looking at the list of actions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#web) but I don't see anything that instantly jumps out at me as being the correct action.

Use case for this is to allow other people (and also programmatic users) in other subscriptions, permission to use an Azure Function as an action when creating an Action Group for alerts (eg Monitor or Application Insights).

Comment: Hi have you checked my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 3):

RBAC roles cannot do this thing (allows someone to ONLY trigger an Azure Function) for you.

It is used to restrict a user (or service principal) to access the Azure resource. For example: `microsoft.web/sites/functions/read` role allows you to get Web Apps Functions. `microsoft.web/sites/functions/write` role allows you to update Web Apps Functions.

[image]

There is no a good option to meet your requirement. But for restricting users to use your function app (trigger Azure Function), you should consider configure the **Authorization level** and **App Service Authentication**.

**Authorization level** controls whether the function requires an API key and which key to use; Function uses a function key; Admin uses your master key. The function and master keys are found in the 'keys' management panel on the portal, when your function is selected. For user-based authentication, go to Function App Settings.

After you configure **App Service Authentication**, you will need an access token to trigger the function app. An [Azure AD Authentication example](https://cuteprogramming.wordpress.com/2019/01/02/authenticate-an-azure-function-with-azure-active-directory/) for your reference.

In this way, you don't need to assign any RBAC role to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this could work, but still requires use of tokens, which is difficult for my use case, but seems to be the only way.

Comment: @Slushysnowman it requires tokens to be sent under the hood, which is what the portal does anyway, but the user will just go to the functionapp's URL, be redirected to microsoft login and back and if they have the permission, the function will run.